# Implementing an if clause in simple bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I've got a bash script that makes use of   `cal -m $v` where `v` is number . The user is prompted for `v`'s value at the beginning of the execution .
In case the user presses `ENTER` instead of introducing a number I want the script to output the days of the current month, namely execute just `cal` instead of  `cal -m $v` .
Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do better, we can [do a range check](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118856/check-if-reply-is-in-a-range-of-numbers) to make sure it's between 1 and 12 inclusively. There are about a billion ways of doing this but here are a couple:

```
if [ "$v" -ge 1 -a "$v" -le 12 ]; then
    cal -m "$v"
else
    cal
fi
```

Or use an arithmetic test:

```
((v>=1 && v<=12)) && cal -m "$v" || cal
```